# Set Column Width of JTable by Percentage

Tags: java, swing, percentage, jtableheader, preferredsize

I need to assign a fixed width to a few columns of a `JTable` and then an equal width to all the other columns.

Suppose a `JTable` has 5 columns. The first column should have a width of 100 and the second one a width of 150. If the remaining width of the `JTable` is 600 after setting the width of the two columns, I'd like to evenly split it among the other three columns.

The problem is `table.getParent().getSize().width` is often 0, even if it is added to the `JFrame` and visible, so I can't use it as a basis.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If an answer works for u, accept it.

Answer (score 16):

```
public MyJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    resizeColumns();
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            resizeColumns();
        }
    });
}
//SUMS 1
float[] columnWidthPercentage = {0.2f, 0.55f, 0.1f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f};

private void resizeColumns() {
    // Use TableColumnModel.getTotalColumnWidth() if your table is included in a JScrollPane
    int tW = jTable1.getWidth();
    TableColumn column;
    TableColumnModel jTableColumnModel = jTable1.getColumnModel();
    int cantCols = jTableColumnModel.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < cantCols; i++) {
        column = jTableColumnModel.getColumn(i);
        int pWidth = Math.round(columnWidthPercentage[i] * tW);
        column.setPreferredWidth(pWidth);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen :)

Comment: Note that you can use [`TableColumnModel.getTotalColumnWidth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#getTotalColumnWidth()) in case your table is included in a `JScrollPane` (which is usually the case).

Comment: little late to the party but columnWidthPercentage should add up to 1.0, otherwise your table will grow very fast

Answer (score 5):

> I need to assign a fixed width to a few columns of a JTable and then an equal width to all the other columns.

Let the table's resize mode do the work for you. Set the resize mode to all columns and set the min/max values of the fixed columns:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableLayout extends JPanel
{
    public TableLayout()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTable table = new JTable(5, 7);
        add( new JScrollPane( table ) );

        table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS );
        TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("A");
        columnA.setMinWidth(100);
        columnA.setMaxWidth(100);
        TableColumn columnC = table.getColumn("C");
        columnC.setMinWidth(50);
        columnC.setMaxWidth(50);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableLayout() );
        frame.setSize(600, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: the `column.setPreferredWidth()` doesn't work when the resize mode is `AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS` so `setMin/MaxWidth()` have to be used.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `table.getPreferredSize()` instead. Try this code snippet:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class Tests {

    private void initGUI(){        
        Object[] tableHeader = new Object[]{"Name", "Category", "Color","Ranking"};
        DefaultTableModel dftm = new DefaultTableModel(tableHeader, 0);        
        dftm.addRow(new Object[]{"Watermelon","Fruit","Green and red",3});
        dftm.addRow(new Object[]{"Tomato","Vegetable","Red",5});
        dftm.addRow(new Object[]{"Carrot","Vegetable","Orange",2});

        JTable table = new JTable(dftm);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        Dimension tableSize = table.getPreferredSize();
        table.getColumn("Name").setPreferredWidth(100);
        table.getColumn("Category").setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumn("Color").setPreferredWidth(Math.round((tableSize.width - 250)* 0.70f));
        table.getColumn("Ranking").setPreferredWidth(Math.round((tableSize.width - 250)* 0.30f));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 new Tests().initGUI();
            }
        });        

    }
}
```

As you'll see, `Name` column will have a width of 100, `Category` will have a width of 150, `Color` column will fit at 70% of remanent width and `Ranking` will fit at last 30%.

**Update**

Based on this comment:

> Thanks, but this will not work if the JFrame's size is set explicitly
>   larger than the JTable...

Solution could be play with `setMinWidth` and `setMaxWidth` methods to fix static columns width, or you can implement your own [TableColumnModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableColumnModelListener.html). In the example above replace `setPreferredWith` lines as follows and try set frame's preferred size as you wish:

```
    final JTable table = new JTable(dftm);        
    table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
            table.columnAdded(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
            table.columnRemoved(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
            table.columnMoved(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            Dimension tableSize = table.getSize();
            table.getColumn("Name").setWidth(100);
            table.getColumn("Category").setWidth(150);
            table.getColumn("Color").setWidth(Math.round((tableSize.width - 250)* 0.70f));
            table.getColumn("Ranking").setWidth(Math.round((tableSize.width - 250)* 0.30f));
        }

        @Override
        public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            table.columnSelectionChanged(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work if the JFrame's size is set explicitly larger than the JTable...

Comment: I see your point. What about play with `setMinWidth` and `setMaxWidth` methods? For instance for your first column you can call `setMinWidth(100)` and `setMaxWidth(100)`. Its width will always be 100 regardless frame's size and even on frame's resizing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to dynamically set my table columns width for a project that had to display correctly on different screen resolution DPI settings. The idea for my solution came from dic19s answer.

Basically I got the preferred size of the JPanel where the JSrollPane of the JTable was placed and work great. Please see below

```
Dimension tableSize =  tableScrollPanePanel.getPreferredSize();
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(Math.round(tableSize.width*0.35f));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(Math.round(tableSize.width*0.215f));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(Math.round(tableSize.width*0.20f));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(Math.round(tableSize.width*0.10f));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(Math.round(tableSize.width*0.10f));
```

Hope this helps somebody

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It think it would be easier to use (and re-use) relative component resizing  if we encapsulate it in an own class. Since I also was confronted with the same issue, I would like to post my code here.

From a client perspective I would like to do something like this

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = jTable.getColumnModel();

TableColumn firstColumn = columnModel.getColumn(0);
TableColumn secondColumn = columnModel.getColumn(1);

ComponentResize<TableColumn> columnResize = new TableColumnResize();
RelativeWidthResizer<TableColumn> relativeWidthResizer = new RelativeWidthResizer<TableColumn>(columnResize);

relativeWidthResizer.setRelativeWidth(firstColumn, 0.8);
relativeWidthResizer.setRelativeWidth(secondColumn, 0.2);

jTable.addComponentListener(relativeWidthResizer);
```

So I first defined the `ComponentResize` interface and implement a `TableColumnResize`

```
public interface ComponentResize<T> {
    public void setWidth(T component, int width);
}

public class TableColumnResize implements ComponentResize<TableColumn> {

    public void setWidth(TableColumn component, int width) {
        component.setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
}
```

The `ComponentResize` interface decouples the way a component's size is set from the concrete APIs. E.g. a `TableColumn`'s width can be set via `setPreferredWidth(int)` while a `JComponent`'s size can be set by `setPreferredWidth(Dimension)`

Than I implemented the `RelativeWidthResizer` that encapsulates the relative width calculation logic.

```
public class RelativeWidthResizer<T> extends ComponentAdapter {

    private Map<T, Double> relativeWidths = new HashMap<T, Double>();
    private ComponentResize<T> componentResize;

    public RelativeWidthResizer(ComponentResize<T> componentResize) {
        this.componentResize = componentResize;
    }

    public void setRelativeWidth(T component, double relativeWidth) {
        if (relativeWidth < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Relative width must be greater or equal to 0.0");
        }

        if (relativeWidth > 1.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Relative width must be less or equal to 1.0");
        }

        double totalRelativeWidth = 0.0;
        for (Double relativeComponentWidth : relativeWidths.values()) {
            totalRelativeWidth += relativeComponentWidth.doubleValue();
        }

        double availableRelativeWidth = 1.0d - (totalRelativeWidth + relativeWidth);

        boolean totalPercentageExceeded = availableRelativeWidth < 0;
        if (totalPercentageExceeded) {
            double remainingRelativeWidth = 1.0d - totalRelativeWidth;
            String message = MessageFormat.format(
                    "Can't set component's relative width to {0}."
                            + " {1} relative width remaining", relativeWidth,
                    remainingRelativeWidth);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }

        relativeWidths.put(component, relativeWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        Component component = e.getComponent();
        apply(component);
    }

    public void apply(Component baseComponent) {
        Dimension size = baseComponent.getSize();
        int maxWidth = (int) size.getWidth();

        int remaining = maxWidth;

        Set<Entry<T, Double>> entrySet = relativeWidths.entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<T, Double>> entrySetIter = entrySet.iterator();

        while (entrySetIter.hasNext()) {
            Entry<T, Double> componentEntry = entrySetIter.next();
            T componentToResize = componentEntry.getKey();
            Double relativeWidth = componentEntry.getValue();

            int width = (int) (maxWidth * relativeWidth.doubleValue());
            remaining -= width;

            boolean lastComponent = !entrySetIter.hasNext();
            if (lastComponent && remaining > 0) {
                width += remaining;
            }
            componentResize.setWidth(componentToResize, width);
        }
    }
}
```