# Can we set/adjust size of JTable column as per the size of GUI Component?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my project,i need to adjust the sizes of columns in `JTable` as per the sizes of GUI Components such as `JComboBox` and `JTextField`. Can we adjust the size of column as per the size of GUI Component ?

Comment: Did u take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)?

Comment: No i didn't,i just tried to get the size of component and set to the column but the size of column seems to be in pixels so it didn't worked,i will take a look at mentioned link.

Comment: See [TableColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html). And see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19012691/2587435)

Answer (score 1):

> but the size of column seems to be in pixels

What is the problem with that? The size of Swing components are also in pixels.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting and Changing Column Widths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width) for more information.